# URL Redirect in a Loop

Tags: javascript, api, loops

I am using a java script in php to redirect a URL. This works for me because each time the loop is run, the link opens in a new window and the desired action takes place. However I want to stop the script from opening new windows and run / load within the same page. If I open the link the same page, it redirects to the new page in the first run and the loop does not run further.

I have no control over the next pages as they are part of an API. I do not actually want to navigate to the new page(s) but I just want to run the http:// API, which may even run in the background or something.

Please advise on what would be the best method to handle this ?

This is my current script:

```
<?php

$x1=$_POST["textfield1"]; 

$msg = "New Message Alert From $x1. blah blah";

$query = "SELECT * FROM phone_list";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

$i=0;

while ($i < $num)
{

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"phone");

echo'<script> window.open("http://linktonextpage&msg='.$msg.'&num='.$f1'"); </script>';

$i++;
}

?>
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Try using `ajax` to make the call...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're discovering, once you move from one page to another at that point the previous page is *gone* from the browser.  JavaScript won't continue to run from pages that are no longer loaded.

> I do not actually want to navigate to the new page(s) but I just want to run the http:// API, which may even run in the background or something.

Then don't navigate to the page.  Instead, make an AJAX request to the desired URL.  Something as simple as this:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // This function is called when the AJAX request completes.
    // Here you would check for errors or respond in some way, if needed.
};
xhttp.open('GET', 'http://someurl', true);
xhttp.send();
```

As long as you're not making too many concurrent requests, you can run that in a loop.  Just enclose it in a function:

```
function sendRequest(url) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // This function is called when the AJAX request completes.
        // Here you would check for errors or respond in some way, if needed.
    };
    xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

And call that function in a loop over your urls:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myUrls.length; i++) {
    sendRequest(url);
}
```

You can get a lot fancier with this pretty easily, passing the callback function into the `sendRequest()` function or having `sendRequest()` return the AJAX promise or lots of other things.  It's up to you what further features you want to add.  The main point here, in response to your statement above, is simply to make AJAX requests in the background rather than navigate the browser to the URLs.

---

Note: Currently your loop is *server-side*, which is emitting a lot of repeated code to the browser.  You can probably just emit the JSON-encoded values and perform the loop client-side as demonstrated above.  Or, if you *really* want to loop server-side, then just define a function like the one above and emit calls to that function in a loop.  It's still a lot of repeated client-side code, but it'll get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - less correct than solution with AJAX,
but very simple:

You can add iframes instead of opening popups.

```
while(...){
  echo '<iframe src="http://linktonextpage&msg='.$msg.'&num='.$f1'." width="100%" height="120"></iframe>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code it seems like you want to send messages to all the numbers fetched from database so if you want to use JavaScript you can do as previous answer.

Another way of doing the same is without using JavaScript.

You can also make Curl request to the Api Urls. Within your PHP code without loading the page.

```
While (condition) { $service_url = 'http://linktonextpage&msg='.$msg.'&num='.$f1'';
   $curl = curl_init($service_url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);}
```